# Elementary Sync Method For Audio Video Streaming

Tags: java, android, sockets, synchronization, streaming

Lets say I have some h264 video nal units and some g726 audio samples crammed into a structure I send across a socket.

Each video and audio packet comes with a UTC timestamp of when it was recorded.

The data is sent down a TCP socket.  Yes I know, not great for streaming but removes some issues I don't want to tackle.

I am then using Android MediaCodec to decode the h264 nal units which is rendered to a Surface and g726++ to decode the received audio data which is then played through AudioTrack.

This is all working great except for the streams are definitely out of sync.

The timestamps I have are from the encoder.

How can I use these timestamps to sync the video to the audio on the decoders end.  AudioTrack has a getPlaybackHeadPosition which based on sample rate can be used to calculate its progress.  MediaCodec has the presentation time.  Along with the time stamps from the encoder I think I have enough information to sync the two streams.

Any advice welcome.

Comment: 'Yes I know, not great for streaming' - well, it's a streaming protocol, so I don't understand that at all.

Comment: 'This is all working great except for the streams are definitely out of sync.' - you have only one stream and TCP data is not received out-of-order.

Comment: 'How can I use these timestamps to sync the video to the audio on the decoders end.' - yes, video streaming is difficult.  You have to accept latency, and you have to accept buffering.  Maintaining high and low water marks in the buffer queue and clocking out the data from the queue at an appropriate rate re. timestamps and latency is not awesomely difficult, but you have to, well, do it:(  'Elementary' and 'audio/video streaming' do not belong in the same question.

Comment: Typically UDP is used for streaming and you manage the ordering on the end point.  I am using TCP to skip that.  It is out of sync in terms of playback, yes I receive everything in order but if I do naive playback there is a large gap between audio and video (ie. no lip sync).  I am not looking for a perfect lip sync solution, I am looking to get close.  The timestamps I have are based on the encoders wall clock.  The receiver gets these timestamps fine I am just not sure where to go from there in terms of sync`n the playback.

Comment: Are the video and audio streams continuous? If so, presumably the out of synch offset is constant and if you can work it out and delay which ever starts first by the offset they would be in synch? Or are they lots of separate discrete audio and video samples with only the UTC timestamps to indicate when they should play - this would be much harder.